# How this react-redux exports connect?

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-redux

As per this [file](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/f892ec00d7e92ff7afb21498276472f0e3b000c5/src/index.js) `connect` is imported from the [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/f892ec00d7e92ff7afb21498276472f0e3b000c5/src/connect/connect.js) module using the ES6 syntax. The [connect.js](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/f892ec00d7e92ff7afb21498276472f0e3b000c5/src/connect/connect.js) does not export `connect` but `createConnect` class.

How the `connect` is exported from the [connect.js](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/f892ec00d7e92ff7afb21498276472f0e3b000c5/src/connect/connect.js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `index.js` the following import statement is used:

```
import connect from './connect/connect'
```

That imports the default export from `./connect/connect` and assigns it to the name `connect` (you can name it whatever you want).

In `connect.js` the default export is on [Line 90](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/f892ec00d7e92ff7afb21498276472f0e3b000c5/src/connect/connect.js#L90):

```
export default createConnect()
```

This exports the [return value of the `createConnect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/f892ec00d7e92ff7afb21498276472f0e3b000c5/src/connect/connect.js#L47), which is the function `connect`. Note that the name is not important, but it's common and logical to give it the same name as the module, it technically doesn't even need a name.

For details about default exports and imports see: [Exploring ES6 - Default exports](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_default-exports-one-per-module)